# function().function() VS function()function()

Tags: php

I was writing a foreach Loop in PHP5.
Here is the script:

```
foreach(range('A','Z') as $char) // line 1
{ // line 2
echo strtoupper($char)strtolower($char); // line 3
} // line 4
```

And I got this error message
Parse error: parse error, unexpected T_STRING in testing.php on line 3

I spent almost an hour to figure out I should add a dot between two functions like this:

```
echo strtoupper($char).strtolower($char);
```

So I can't tell the difference between these two lines of codes:

```
echo strtoupper($char).strtolower($char);
echo strtoupper($char)strtolower($char);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The '.' is a concatenation operator. It returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments.

For example:

```
'Hello ' . 'world!'
```

gives:

```
'Hello world!'
```

Having two functions next to each other without any operators is an error.

Answer (score 4):

`PHP`'s grammar expects the arguments of `echo` to be an `expression` or a set of `expressions` separated by comma.

Now `strtoupper($char)` is a complete expression by itself. After this expression PHP expects to see an expression separator which could be a `comma`, `dot` or even a `semi-colon` but when it finds a `string` (`strtolower`) it complains.

So

```
strtoupper($char)strtolower($char);
```

is not a valid expression but these are:

```
strtoupper($char),strtolower($char);
strtoupper($char).strtolower($char);
strtoupper($char);strtolower($char);
```

But in your case the last one does not server the purpose as it prints only the 26 uppercase letters and does not print the lowercase ones.